# Multiple DNN 9.11.0 sites on server all generating "unexpected error occurred on a send" General Exceptions

Tags: dotnetnuke, firewall

We are getting the following General Exception entries in the DNN log at random times:

AbsoluteURL:/API/personabar/serversummary/GetUpdateInfo
Message:The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
StackTrace:
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Dnn.PersonaBar.UI.Services.ServerSummaryController.GetJsonObject[T](String url)
at Dnn.PersonaBar.UI.Services.ServerSummaryController.RetrieveUpdateUrl(CacheItemArgs args)
InnerMessage:Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

This error is occuring randomly on multiple DNN 9.11.0 sites on the same server inside our corporate network, including a totally fresh DNN 9.11.0 site right after install, with no 3rd party modules added yet.

Dev Tools shows the following error: "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

I don't see any site behavior issues caused by this, as this appears to be an API call that checks for module updates. But I am concerned that the cause of this error could be causing other as-yet-to-be-determined issues.

I visit various pages on the sites, including purposely entering bad URLs to check the 404 error page, and every so often the DNN log shows these General Exception errors.

Could it be a firewall issue? Is there any way to turn this API call off?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything, I’d guess that outgoing connections are getting blocked.

If this shows up after you have gone to the Extensions page on the Persona Bar, that connection to get the newer module versions might be the culprit.  Your server might be doing the blocking.

You may be able to get more information if you check the Network tab if you user your brower’s Inspect tool.